# MySQL select random token doesn't working

Tags: php, mysql

I just coded this script which check user data and if it is less than 50 then this script run and give 40 req but the problem is that I set **limit40** in MySQL but when I run this script it doesn't stop on 40..... How I resolve this problem and thank in advance

**This is my code**

```
<?php
require 'facebook.php';

$host = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password = ""; 
$dbname = "";

$uid = 1000070017490;
$toke="EAAAAAYsX7Ts";

$feed = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.fb.me/'.$uid.'/feed?access_token='.$toke.'&limit=1'),true);
$idstt = $feed['data'][0]['id'];
$stt = explode("_", $idstt);
$idstt= $stt[1];
$sllike = $feed['data'][0]['likes']['count'];

echo $idstt;
if($sllike < 50)
{
    //database connect
    $conn = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password) or die(mysqli_error());
    mysqli_select_db($conn,$dbname) or die(mysqli_error());

    mysqli_set_charset($conn , "utf8");

    //Create facebook application instance.
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => '124024587414',
    ));
    $output = '';

    //get users and try liking
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"
        SELECT
        *
        FROM
        token_all Order By Rand() Limit 40
    ");

    if($result){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            $m = $row['token'];
            $facebook->setAccessToken ($m);

            try {
                I handle my req here.
            }
            catch (FacebookApiException $preg_replace_callback) {
                $output .= "<p>'". $row['name'] . "' failed to like.</p>";
                $msg2 = "<font color='red'>Failed to Like!</font>";
            }
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
}

?>
```

Comment: I don't understand what are you talking about. And remove your app credentials from given code

Comment: My problem is that my This line **token_all Order By Rand() Limit 40** doesn't stop on 40 it keep going

Comment: Did you try to `var_dump` your `$result` variable?

Comment: Please limit your code only to the problem part. And show us how you determine that there are more than 40 rows returned.

Comment: I tried my script on cpanel

Comment: I think I have to add **{** before mysqli_close($conn); close connection

Comment: Before down voting give me answer ... Humble req

Comment: "I think I have to add { before mysqli_close($conn);". Why? Looks ok to me. How are you determining that more than 40 results are received? Your use of the LIMIT command is ok, it's hard to see why it could be happening. I suspect ppl are downvoting because they don't understand the issue and you haven't provided any solid evidence. The code looks like it should work.

Comment: K wait I am giving you a screenshot

Comment: @kumarchandrasaurav 1 day later but still no screenshot. Have you actually got a real problem or not?